# Displaying data from database issue

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to display all the rows in my data from my data of my specific user but its only displaying 1 row and not updating.
the code is -

```
$user = $_SESSION["username"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE sender OR receiver = ?";
if ($sql = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
    $sql->bind_param("s",$user);
    if ($sql->execute()) {
        $result = $sql->get_result();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                 echo "<br> sender: ". $row["sender"]. " - receiver: ". $row["receiver"]. " -amount:" . $row["amount"] . "<br>";
                }
            }
            $sql->close();
            $conn->close();
        }else{ echo "0 result"; }
    }


?>
```

Comment: How many rows do you have in your database?

Comment: every transactions is a new row so the number of rows always changing

Comment: I suggest first fire the select query in your database with entering value in place of ? and see how much rows it returns.

Comment: `sender OR receiver = ?` is not the right syntax in SQL. You must do `sender = ? OR receiver = ?` and bind two parameters.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are using wrong SQL formation & passing just receiver value. I suggest below changes:

Replaced

1) `WHERE sender OR receiver = ?` with `WHERE sender=? OR receiver = ?`

2) `$sql->bind_param("s",$user);` with `$sql->bind_param("ss",$user,$user);`

```
$user = $_SESSION["username"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE sender=? OR receiver = ?";
if ($sql = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
    $sql->bind_param("ss",$user,$user);
    if ($sql->execute()) {
        $result = $sql->get_result();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                 echo "<br> sender: ". $row["sender"]. " - receiver: ". $row["receiver"]. " -amount:" . $row["amount"] . "<br>";
                }
            }
            $sql->close();
            $conn->close();
        }else{ echo "0 result"; }
    }
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: What have you changed? Could you explain this solution?

Comment: I explained it by editing my answer. Check the answer.